# Shortest code for depleting a generator in code golfing

Tags: python, generator

Given that you don't care about the actual output, what is a way to deplete a generator?

The function I use in a map will print on itself, so all I have to do is to get the map to evaluate.

For now, I use `list()` to do this, but I'm looking for a shorter way.

Arbitrary example:

```
list(map(print,range(10)))
```

Comment: Switch to Python 2.7, where `map` doesn't return a generator. Only half joking ;-)

Comment: Use a `for`-loop. What's wrong with that? (Also think at the poor souls that will have to read your code! :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini OP mentioned it's for code golf.

Comment: @Kevin Then `print_function` needs to be imported - this ungolfs a lot. :)

Comment: Assuming you have to use map(print, range(10)), in the code, and python3.x, it doesn't look like you could get much shorter.

Comment: @Totem Except for that I would need to deplete it to actually get the printing done.

Comment: Think you tagged me by mistake there

Comment: Doesn't this question belong on [programming puzzles and code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.5, you can abuse the [additional unpacking generalizations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448) and replace:

```
list(map(print,range(10)))
```

with:

```
*map(print,range(10)),
```

saving four characters (it produces a `tuple` of `None`s).

With 3.4 and earlier, you can (assuming a one character long literal exists which won't exist in the output) do:

```
0in map(print,range(10))  # tokenizer is fine with no space between 0 and in
```

which saves two characters while also avoiding storing any intermediate `list`s.

If the outputs aren't controlled at all, and you're below 3.5, as others have noted, saving a single character is easy (e.g. just replace `list` with `any`, if only "falsy" values possible, `all` if only "truthy" values possible, or `set()` for all values, at the expense of storing the `set`), but the above save a bit more if you have version or generator output guarantees.

Obviously, if you don't need to `print`, this can shorten even more, since `*somegen,` will do the work with no pointless `print`s, requiring only two characters more than referencing the generator in the first place.

Comment: Yea, I'm aware the code in the example is strange, but it was mostly there to produce `None`'s I don't care about, while still having all the results evaluated. Really to just deplete a generator. `*X,` is a great solution.

Comment: @PascalvKooten: Ah, so the `map` was an example of making a generator in the first place, and you were looking for shorter code to exhaust the `map` than `list()`, not shortening the `map` itself or anything. Gotcha. Yeah, I doubt you'll get it down below two characters of overhead. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`Set` is one character shorter than `list`.

```
set(map(print,range(10)))
```

A list comprehension may be better in some cases:

```
[print(a)for a in range(10)]
```

Comment: Well, for brevity, if you're dropping `map`, don't use list comprehension. `for a in range(10):print(a)` is one char shorter after all; you don't need to make a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your generator will not contain one of the single-digit integers (for example `2`) you can deplete it with `2 in ...` which is one character less than `list(...)`.

Comment: As I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495629/364696), the tokenizer is fine with `2in` rather than `2 in`, so that would shave another character.